# Does Hoor mean Companions?

Tags: jannah

I know I asked similar questions before it's because I'm really struggling to accept this concept so I went to sheik and he said to me that women get hoors too since Hoor is plural of haw ra and ahwar.

Does Hoor mean companions or females!

Answer (score 1):

Understanding Quran using dictionaries only, will lead to wrong statements like: "women get hoors too" , which has never been stated ever by any scholar before ever.

ِAlso in Quran it says : "Hoor-un maksurat" / "حور مقصورات"

maksurat = refers to females only. 
If they were men , it would have been : "maksurun" / "مقصورون"

They are females.

for more, see also:

https://islamqa.info/en/60188

Heaven has all the pleasures for all men and women , a woman will have the best husband , so she will not have to worry about having multiple husbands. Because she will reach ultimate happiness with just one husband.

All she has to worry about , really , is entering Heaven in the first place, and work hard in this life to get to heaven in the hereafter .

Don't let shaytan fool you .